# React.js Router url is resolving from browser but not from Link within App

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a component setup in react router that has the following url

```
http://localhost:3000/editing/5f0d7484706b6715447829a2
```

The component is called from a parent component using the <Link.. syntax and when I click the button in the parent component the url above appears in the browser but my app crashes.

The error applies to the first manipulation the component does with the data - which indicates to me that the app is running before the data is available. This does not happen elsewhere in the app.

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
```

If I then refresh the url in the browser it works as intended. The component also loads fine if I just paste the above url into the browser.

The code is below

```
const Button = (props) => {
  //main props
  const { buttonFunction, buttonIconName, buttonStyle, visible } = props;


  return (
        <Link
        to='./editing/'+props.documentId}
        </Link>

  );
};


export default Button;
```

The called component is below

```
mport React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import DocumentEditor from '../documentEditor/documentEditor';
import DocumentContext from '../../context/Document/DocumentContext';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';



//For testing this Id works
// 5f0d7484706b6715447829a2

//Wrappers

const Editing = ({ match }) => {

  //styling
  const documentContext = useContext(DocumentContext);
  const { Documents, myFiltered, getDocuments, loading, getDocument } = documentContext;


  useEffect(() => {
    getDocument(match.params.documentid);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {Documents !== null && !loading ? (
        <DocumentEditor
          Document={Documents}
          DocumentContext={documentContext}
          documentMode='edit'
        />
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Editing;
```

### My Thoughts

I suspect it may be due to the form loading prior to the data has been fetched but I don't see how as the code

```
{Documents !== null && !loading ? (
```

along with my functions that have been pulling data have been working fine for ages and use async / await should prevent this. Maybe I shouldn't be using a link in this way?

Comment: error is about `reduce()` method call on an `undefined` value. Where is the code with `reduce()` method call?

Comment: Hi the reduce() error is missleading as the reason for the error is due to no data. (I have put the function that is spevied in the question)

Comment: _I have put the function that is spevied in the question_ - Where is that function? I can't see it in your question

Answer (score 0):

As @Yousaf says in the comments, your specific error is regarding a `reduce()` call, and we can't see that in the code you posted.

I do see what appears to be a typo, and that may be your issue.

At the top of your file, you're importing `DocumentContext` with a capital "D"

```js
import DocumentContext from '../../context/Document/DocumentContext';
```

And inside your `Editing` component, you're destructuring `documentContext` with a lowercase "d":

```js
const { Documents, myFiltered, getDocuments, loading, getDocument } = documentContext;
```

This would lead to `{ Documents, myFiltered, getDocuments, loading, getDocument }` all being `undefined`. You're then passing `Documents` and `documentContext` to the `DocumentEditor`, which presumably is trying to call `reduce()` on one of those things that are passed, which are `undefined`.

Comment: sorry about that. I removed a line in error that pulled out the context " const documentContext = useContext(DocumentContext);" when I cleaned up the code to submit it. I have pasted the full code into the question

Comment: Is the `getDocument` call from the Context meant to update `Documents` from the Context? Can we see your Context code?